# Unable to enable/disable button based on dropdown value selected before form submit

Tags: jquery, jsp

I want to enable 'Update' button if i select 'System' from dropdown and should be disabled if I select other value from dropdown. By default 'Update' button should be disabled'.When I select value other than 'System' from dropdown the button should be disabled.

```
DataSync.jsp


<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.HashMap" %>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="Css/motoCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
<meta http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true">
<script type="text/javascript">
function getProjectDetails()
{  
    alert('inside getProjectDetails()') 
    window.open(document.dataSyncForm.action="ProjectDetails.jsp","mywindow","menubar=0,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,width=500,height=400");
}

</script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <s:form name="dataSyncForm" action="dataSyncUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" theme="simple" >
        <div style="margin-left:45%;margin-top:10%;"><h4>Data Sync</h4></div>
        <div style="margin-left:40%;margin-top:5%">
            <div>
            <span style="display:inline"><s:text name="Data table"/></span>
            <span>
                <select name="dataTable" onchange="if (this.value==''||this.value=='Warranty'||this.value=='AMC'||this.value=='PriceList') this.form.Update.style.display='none';">
                    <option value="">Select</option>
                    <option value="Warranty">Warranty</option>
                    <option value="AMC">AMC</option>
                    <option value="System">System</option>
                    <option value="PriceList">Price list</option>
                </select>
            </span>

            </div>
            <div>&nbsp</div>
            <div>
                <span style="display:inline"><s:text name="Upload file"/></span>
                <span><s:file name="dataFile" label="Select file" size="40" /></span>
            </div>
            <div>&nbsp</div>
            <div>
                <input type="button" class="btn" id="btnUpdate" name="Update" value="Update" style="display:inline" onclick="javascript:getProjectDetails();">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Upload" style="display:inline">
                <input type="button" class="btn" value="Cancel" style="display:inline"> 
            </div>

        </div>

    </s:form>

    </body>
     <HEAD>

</HEAD>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
$('select').change(function () {
   if (this.value === 'System') {
      $('#btnUpdate').attr('disabled', false);
   } else {
      $('#btnUpdate').attr('disabled', true);  
   }
});
```

To set `Update` button disabled as default, you could put the following statement into the `ready` of `document`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#btnUpdate').attr('disabled', true);  
});
```

Hope this help you sorting the issue out.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help @Tung,Your answer helped me to solve the issue.Thanks once again

Comment: @ChanduBawge: Please vote my response if it helped you solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
function getComboA(selectObject) {
    var value = selectObject.value;  
    if(value == "System")
    {
    document.getElementsByTagName('Update').style.display='inline';
    }
}
```

### Your HTML

```
<select name="dataTable" onchange="getComboA(this)">

<input type="button" class="btn" id="btnUpdate" name="Update" value="Update" style="display:none" onclick="javascript:getProjectDetails();">
```

By default Update button will be `display:none` and onChange of select it will be `display:inline`.

Also display:none and disable are different things. Disable will show the button on view page but user won't be able to click it while display:none will  hide the button from page.

Comment: Not sure why you would answer a question about disabling a button, by giving code to hide the button and explaining the difference between disabling and hiding.  OP wants to disable the button - this answer is not relevant.

Comment: In the code above he has used display:none instead of disable. He might not know the difference between two things. So I have given the explanation and gave my answer according to his code. Hope now it make sense? @Archer

Comment: Ok you can give your answer according to the question and help him. :) @Archer

Comment: Yes, thanks.  I know I can.  You can alter yours so it answers the actual question as well, but that's not going to happen either.